# Is there an idiom or euphemism for when someone has an average/small penis but knows how to use it?

Tags: idioms, euphemisms

Really, what the question title states. In my language there's a more "flowery" phrase to say "size doesn't matter". It would roughly translate to "even a small clown can work in the big top" – I'm looking for something that tries to maintain the wit of the "small"/"big" antithesis.

Comment: Napoleon complex?

Comment: @RonanMurphy — Not quite what I'm going for – a Napoleon complex is for when you're deliberately overcompensating for a deficiency. What I'm looking for is a way to point out to someone they shouldn't assume a small size implies a bad performance. (Doesn't necessarily have to be a phrase that only applies to sex of course.)

Comment: **It's not the size of the boat, it's the motion of the ocean.** comes (no pun intended) to mind...although I do find the Slovakian saying quite humorous.

Comment: I was just wondering did you have one yourself ;) To extend on JSanchez's suggestion - **It's not the size of the boat nor the motion in the ocean, it's whether or not the captain can stay in port long enough for all the passengers to get off**

Comment: @JSanchez Oh! I've actually heard that before, and it's pretty much what I was looking for. Make it into an answer :)

Comment: @Jsanchez Yeah, that's the more sensible version of mine below.

Comment: @RonanMurphy "It's not the size of the boat, nor the motion of the ocean but rather how well the guy uses his penis."   That's how my grandmother used to say it.  ;-p

Comment: @DavidM or indeed, "It's not the size of the boat, but does the guy not know how to use his hands and mouth? Oh you poor girl, you need to get him some education".

Comment: A related question: Is there any expression used in English for this that doesn't have a stronger effect on making the speaker immediately less sexually attractive than their having a small penis did?

Comment: "Person skilled in the art" works in patent law: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Person_having_ordinary_skill_in_the_art

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**It's not the size of the boat, it's the motion of the ocean.** comes (no pun intended) to mind, although I'm sure there are many more.

Comment: "not the length of the wand, but the magic in the stick"

Comment: similar to @Roger: "it's not the wand, but the skill of the wizard"

Answer (score 10):

One that applies to more than just sex (expressing small size doesn't imply bad performance) is:

**it's not the size of the dog in the fight, but the size of the fight in the dog**

Answer (score 7):

A commonly used expression (although not an idiom):

> It's not the size that counts, it's how you use it.

Answer (score 3):

"It's not the meat, it's the motion" is the one I've heard most frequently.

Answer (score -2):

**It's a grower not a shower** at least implies function.

Comment: Well, actually that expression means _"It may be small now when it is flaccid, but becomes much larger when it is erect."_